# Want to take employee today task in single row using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Want to display Name, Project name and Date in one row.

```
╔═══════╦════════════════╦═══════════════╦════════╗
║ name  ║    empid       ║ projectname   ║ date   ║
╠═══════╬════════════════╬═══════════════╬════════╣
║ krish ║      1         ║        Num. 1 ║12/5/19 ║
║ krish ║      1         ║        Num. 2 ║11/5/19 ║
║ krish ║      1         ║        Num. 3 ║11/5/19 ║
║ krish ║      1         ║        Num. 4 ║11/5/19 ║
║ selva ║      2         ║        Num. 5 ║12/5/19 ║
║ selva ║      2         ║        Num. 6 ║11/5/19 ║
╚═══════╩════════════════╩═══════════════╩════════╝
```

I have tables like this but i want to display

```
╔═══════╦════════════════╦═══════════════=╦════════╗
║ name  ║    empid       ║ projectname    ║ date   ║
╠═══════╬════════════════╬══════════════=═╬════════╣
║ krish ║      1         ║        Num. 1  ║12/5/19 ║
║ krish ║      1         ║Num.2,Num3,Num 4║11/5/19 ║ 
║ selva ║      2         ║        Num. 5  ║12/5/19 ║
║ selva ║      2         ║        Num. 6  ║11/5/19 ║
```

```
SELECT tblprojects.id as pid,tblemployees.FirstName,tblemployees.LastName,tblemployees.EmpId,tblemployees.id,tblprojects.Project,tblprojects.PostingDate,tblprojects.Status 
from tblprojects 
join tblemployees 
  on tblprojects.empid=tblemployees.id 
order by pid desc
```

```
╔═══════╦════════════════╦═══════════════=╦════════╗
║ name  ║    empid       ║ projectname    ║ date   ║
╠═══════╬════════════════╬══════════════=═╬════════╣
║ krish ║      1         ║        Num. 1  ║12/5/19 ║
║ krish ║      1         ║Num.2,Num3,Num 4║11/5/19 ║ 
║ selva ║      2         ║        Num. 5  ║12/5/19 ║
║ selva ║      2         ║        Num. 6  ║11/5/19 ║
```

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code (php, in this instance)

Answer (score 1):

`GROUP_CONCAT` is used to concat the results by concat in a single string

```
SELECT tblprojects.id as pid,tblemployees.FirstName,tblemployees.LastName,tblemployees.EmpId,tblemployees.id,GROUP_CONCAT(tblprojects.Project),tblprojects.PostingDate,tblprojects.Status 
from tblprojects 
join tblemployees 
  on tblprojects.empid=tblemployees.id 
GROUP BY tblprojects.PostingDate
order by pid desc
```